# Reimplementing lrzip decompress on Windows explorer using WSL

Tags: windows-explorer, batch-file, windows-subsystem-for-linux, command-line-arguments, wsl2

I've downloaded an old version of [lrzip decompressor](https://code.google.com/archive/p/lrzip-decompressor/) for windows and noticed that it's using the cygwin libraries in order to run the program itself.

The benchmarks comparing WSL2 and cygwin say that wsl2 is **much** faster so I'd like to obtain something similar to that program using the lrzip binary from the current WSL Ubuntu install.

Still: I have 2 questions.

1. how to pass to the `wsl` command the correct file path (considering a command like this: `wsl lrzip -d <compressed file to decompress>`, maybe also considering that it would be nice to have the decompressed file in the same folder as the compressed one)
2. how to integrate such a script in the explorer menu (that "lrzip decompressor" shows a "Decompress" command in place of "Open" when you right-click on an .lrz file)

Thanks in advance, sorry but I'm really a noob talking about Windows scripting ('-_-)

Comment: Keep in mind that WSL 2 cannot directly access your Windows filesystems. It’s a virtual machine. Performance will be limited. // I doubt WSL is faster for this use case either way. It’s mostly just computation and I/O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### Summary

- `wslpath` converts Windows paths to the WSL equilvalent
- Create a script to convert the path, but be sure to call it with proper quoting to handle the backslashes in the Windows path.
- Create the registry key to add right-click for the WSL script, with single quotes around the `'%1'` that denotes the filename.  E.g.:

  ```
  wsl -e bash -c "~/.local/bin/lrzipWP '%1'"
  ```

###### But first ...

In this case, there's actually a more important question than, *"How to do it?"*, and that's, *"Where to do it?"*

As @DanielB mentioned in the comments, you *may not* experience the speed increase you are hoping for with WSL2 (spoiler alert: make that *"will not"*).  WSL2 is faster than Cygwin, but some of that advantage comes from the fact that it utilizes its own virtual disk where it can expose a native ext4 filesystem.

So for working with files *inside* that filesystem, yes, WSL2 is great.  However, when you are working with files on the Windows filesystem, it's an entirely different story.  WSL2 accesses files on Windows drives through a (localhost, obviously) network client/server implementation of the 9P protocol.  WSL2 runs the server on the Windows side, and the WSL2 instance access the files through the client implementation (although it really runs both ways).

For situations where you are accessing *multiple small files* on the Windows drive, WSL2 is *very* slow -- Perhaps two orders of magnitude slower than "native" Windows access.

I wasn't quite sure how the "large file" use-case of `lrzip` would work, so I gave it a test on a 535MB Ubuntu server cloud image.  Not huge, but the results were, unfortunately, pretty bad:

```
# From Linux filesystem:

~/tmp> lrzip -d ubuntu-20.04-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk-kvm.img.lrz
Output filename is: ubuntu-20.04-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk-kvm.img
Decompressing...
100%     535.69 /    535.69 MB
Average DeCompression Speed: 133.750MB/s
Output filename is: ubuntu-20.04-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk-kvm.img: [OK] - 561709056 bytes
Total time: 00:00:03.35

# Using Windows filesystem:
lrzip -d /mnt/c/temp/ubuntu-20.04-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk-kvm.img.lrz
Output filename is: /mnt/c/temp/ubuntu-20.04-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk-kvm.img
Decompressing...
100%     535.69 /    535.69 MB
Average DeCompression Speed:  9.068MB/s
Output filename is: /mnt/c/temp/ubuntu-20.04-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk-kvm.img: [OK] - 561709056 bytes

Total time: 00:00:58.26
```

And that's a pretty fast NVMe drive.

###### The workaround

But don't despair.  There's still a good way to do this from WSL; *just not WSL2*.

WSL1 is still around and viable for a reason.  There are still some use-cases where it excels, and this is one of them (side note: simplified network access is another).

While WSL2 has its virtual filesystem (which is fast, as long as you are using that filesystem), WSL1 actually *directly* accesses the Windows drive.

The same test from WSL1?

```
lrzip -d /mnt/c/temp/ubuntu-20.04-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk-kvm.img.lrz
Output filename is: /mnt/c/temp/ubuntu-20.04-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk-kvm.img
Decompressing...
100%     535.69 /    535.69 MB
Average DeCompression Speed: 133.750MB/s
Output filename is: /mnt/c/temp/ubuntu-20.04-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk-kvm.img: [OK] - 561709056 bytes

Total time: 00:00:04.64
```

So definitely, use a WSL1 instance for this.

If this is the only reason you are using WSL, just convert your instance with:

```
wsl --set-version <distroname> 1
```

If you'd like to keep both versions around, that's entirely possible as well:

```
wsl --export <distroname> filename.tar
mkdir <where you want to place the second instance>
wsl --import <newdistroname> <location> filename.tar --version 1
```

###### The script

So (about time you say?) now on to your *actual* question ...

To pass in the Windows path, you'll need to have a wrapper shell script that you call.  Let's call it `lrzipWP` (for Windows Path).

Converting the Windows path to WSL/Linux is done with the `wslpath` command, which is actually (quite creatively, IMHO) injected in to every WSL instance at startup (by `/init` linking the command name to itself).

And getting the directory name of the file to use for the `-O` argument can be done by taking the `dirname` of the file.  Although, after trying this out, you don't need it since the default `lrzip` behavior in Linux is to use the same directory as the file location.  I'll leave it in the script for flexibility in case you need it for some reason.

Since you'll be launching this from the right-click menu, the terminal will close as soon as the script exits, so you'll want to add a `read` statement (or similar) to pause so you can read the output.

Put that together and your script should (hopefully) look something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
lrzip -d $(wslpath "${1}") -O $(dirname $(wslpath "${1}"))
echo "Press <Enter> to Exit"
read
```

Save it to something like `~/.local/bin`.

Give it executable permissions with `chmod +x ~/.local/bin/lrzipWP`.

You can now call it from PowerShell via:

```
wsl -e bash -c "~/.local/bin/lrzipWP 'C:\temp\filename.lrz'"
```

###### Adding to right-click menu for `.lrz` files

While this is mostly covered elsewhere on Super User in [various questions and answers](https://superuser.com/search?q=HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT%5C*%5Cshell%5C), the basics are:

- Run `regedit` in Windows
- Navigate to `Computer -> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` (easy enough, it's right there at the top).
- Right-click on `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` and *New -> Key*
- Name the key `.lrz`
- Right-click on `.lrz` and *New -> Key* again.
- Name this key `shell`
- Right-click on `shell` and *New -> Key* again.
- Name this key `lrz`
- Double-click the `(Default)` property of `lrz` and change it to *"Decompress with WSL lrz"*.
- Right-click on the `lrz` key and *New -> Key* (for the last time).
- Name this key `command`
- Double-click the `(Default)` property of `command` and change it to:

  ```
  wsl -e bash -c "~/.local/bin/lrzipWP '%1'"
  ```

That should (hopefully) do it.

Comment: Well... I've actually tried to benchmark the whole thing on a 350MB file and came to the conclusion that cygwin is actually better than anything else apparently:

`
NATIVE LINUX
Compression Speed: 14.500MB/s.
Total time: 00:00:24.07
DeCompression Speed:  6.327MB/s
Total time: 00:00:55.10

CYGWIN
Compression Speed: 15.130MB/s.
Total time: 00:00:23.23
DeCompression Speed: 69.600MB/s
Total time: 00:00:05.53

WSL2
Compression Speed:  7.250MB/s.
Total time: 00:00:48.97
DeCompression Speed:  0.436MB/s
Total time: 00:13:18.68
`

Comment: @gio91ber Wow - 13 minutes on WSL2 for you.  I'm assuming an HDD, then.  I'd probably still recommend giving WSL1 a try for comparison to Cywin, just for curiosity.  I'd guess it will come in roughly equivalent.  Second note -- I'd encourage you to accept my answer if you feel it addresses your original question, even if you've reached the conclusion you don't need it any longer.  Unanswered questions get automatically "bumped" every so often by the system to see if anyone has new answers.  If someone else *does* come up with an answer you like better, you can always accept it instead.